# select min booking date by each customer

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables, `CustomerMaster`, `EntBookings`, now for each customer, I have record of each of their booking(s) in `EntBookings` table.
What I want is, to find out the first date of booking for all customers.

What I tried,

```
SELECT cm.CustomerCode,
       cm.CustomerName,
       MIN(eb.BookingDate) OVER(PARTITION BY eb.BookingByCustomer)
FROM   EntBookings eb
       INNER JOIN CustomerMaster cm
            ON  cm.CustomerCode = eb.BookingByCustomer
GROUP BY
       cm.CustomerCode,
       cm.CustomerName,
       eb.BookingByCustomer,
       eb.BookingDate
```

It gives the result as

```
Cust1   ABC     2013-01-24 00:00:00.000
Cust2   ABCD    2013-01-24 00:00:00.000
Cust2   ABCD    2013-01-24 00:00:00.000
Cust3   BCD     2013-01-25 00:00:00.000
Cust4   BCDE    2013-01-24 00:00:00.000
Cust7   DEF     2013-01-02 00:00:00.000
```

I don't know why for `Cust2`, its showing 2 rows? How can I get it to return just one row?

If I do this..

```
SELECT cm.CustomerCode,
       cm.CustomerName,
       MIN(eb.BookingDate) OVER(PARTITION BY eb.BookingDate)
FROM   EntBookings eb
       INNER JOIN CustomerMaster cm
            ON  cm.CustomerCode = eb.BookingByCustomer
GROUP BY
       cm.CustomerCode,
       cm.CustomerName,
       eb.BookingByCustomer,
       eb.BookingDate
```

I get this...

```
Cust7   DEF     2013-01-02 00:00:00.000
Cust1   ABC     2013-01-24 00:00:00.000
Cust2   ABCD    2013-01-24 00:00:00.000
Cust4   BCDE    2013-01-24 00:00:00.000
Cust3   BCD     2013-01-25 00:00:00.000
Cust2   ABCD    2013-02-13 00:00:00.000
```

In this case, though I am still getting 2 rows for `Cust2`, dates are wrong, it should be `2013-01-24 00:00:00.000` (as in first case), but that is returning 2 rows. So, both of these queries are incorrect. Can anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are complicating things and you are grouping too much. It seems you only want to group on customer code and name.

```
SELECT 
     cm.CustomerCode, 
     cm.CustomerName, 
     MIN(eb.BookingDate) 
 FROM 
      EntBookings eb
 JOIN
      CustomerMaster cm     ON       
       cm.CustomerCode = eb.BookingByCustomer
 GROUP BY
       cm.CustomerCode, cm.CustomerName
```

Comment: This doesn't works, because it would just simply return the `min` values from `eb.BookingDate` without considering the customer, and the value would be same for all customer(s) regardless of their individual minimum booking date.

Comment: @Razort4x - have you *run* it? It's `GROUP` ing by customer. There will be one row per customer, and the `MIN` will only apply to that group.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever:
Sorry. My bad. I was running it but I was grouping otherwise. It did the work.

Comment: Here's a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/591c2/1) with as much sample data as we currently have.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever:
Thanks and +1 for fiddle, I knew about jsfiddle but not about sqlfiddle.